# Possible to Deref to slice-or-array?

Tags: rust

It feels reasonable to say "I want something that derefs to a slice (or to an array, since I can get a slice from any array trivially)". However the following code doesn't work, yielding the error

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<&[u8; 4] as Deref>::Target == [u8]`
```

```
use core::ops::Deref;
fn foo(x: impl Deref<Target=[u8]>) -> usize {
    x.len()
}

fn bar() {
    let x = [0u8; 4];
    foo(&x); // breaks
    foo(&x[..]); // works
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=43786a9dbdc1e10a909c27ff936ccba4)

Is it possible to create such an abstraction, or is there some reason that this is not a reasonable thing to want?

Comment: I think you want `AsRef<[u8]>` instead, something that can be seen as a `&[u8]`

Comment: You can also just make use of `Deref` and `CoerceUnsized` coercions: `fn foo(x: &[u8])` [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ab354ae340014446057a68e03f6348f)

Comment: Just for the record, every `&T` derefs to `T`. The question is then whether `[T; N]` derefs to `[T]`, and somewhat sensibly the answer is no because `[T; N]` is already “valueish” (as opposed to “pointerish”). But `&array[..]` does deref to `[T]` because it *is* pointerish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo(&x); // breaks
```

That's because [`array`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#) does *not* implement `Deref` trait.

While

```
foo(&x[..]); // works
```

Because [`&T` impl Deref<Target = T>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-for-%26T). So a slice pointer derefs to a slice by construction.

---

Often [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#) is used for smart-pointers and it is not so "generic" implemented on types.

If you want such an abstraction "*As-Is*", maybe you can have a look at [AsRef](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html)

```
fn foo(x: impl AsRef<[u8]>) -> usize {
    x.as_ref().len()
}

fn bar() {
    let x = [0u8; 4];
    foo(&x);             // works
    foo(&x[..]);         // works
    foo(vec![1, 2, 3]);  // also works
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b747f6838c3e1887c8cc590d2285762)

Comment: However, note that if you only use-case is for a function argument to be either an array or a slice, don't use `AsRef`. Just take plain old slice and coercion will do the rest. `AsRef` will just bloat code size and compilation time.